# Geometry Nodes Growing Ivy. Problem with instanced leaves

Tags: geometry-nodes

could you help me out with something? I have made a node setup to create an ivy growing animation on another object. I have come far, but i cant get rid of 2 problems:
when i let my ivy curve grow with my trim curve node, all the leaves i am instancing get a random new seed and switch position. Unfortunately i cant upload a video, but here are 2 pictures in comparison:[image]
[image]

as you can see, i have a complete different seed of leaves, although i just used the trim curve node as little as possible.

also, as you can see, my leaves arent rotated in the right direction. I managed to aim in the direction of my object, the ivy is growing on. But i cant rotate it on the other axis in a way it looks good :/
same for the Scaling
i wasnt able to figure out how i can scale the leaves, as the ivy plant is growing
here is my node tree:
[image]

Help is super apreciated <3 Thx

Comment: Please [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/297737/edit) your question to limit it to a single issue (otherwise it "needs more focus"), and edit the title to reflect the issue in such a way, that someone searching for a similar problem in future might find this thread (otherwise it's "too localized"). See hints on [inconsistent randomization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/288707/60486), and [how to combine two Align Euler to Vector](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294496/60486)

Comment: ..Agreed.. if you reduced  a version of the tree to the smallest  toy version that you can, that still manifests the problem, to isolate it,  you'll help yourself to debug, and others to help you, too.

Comment: Hey Guys, 
I see, sorry for the confusion. I'm overwhelmed myself as you can see ^^. THank you for the help via discord Markus von Broady. You are a blender Hero :D
Do you want me to delete the post here or something?
greets